# I want to extract the text from the image horizontally using java

Tags: java, android, ocr

All of the OCR courses in the tutorials is vertically orientation,

but I want to extract the text horizontally

I have used two course from YouTube

1. **firebase ml kit**
   `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'`
2. **play services**

   `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'`

Comment: did you mix-up vertical and horizontal?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I thought same. Moein Moradi, Do you mean to extract the text Left to Right (or Right to left)?

Comment: @Derek I think he wants top to bottom...

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko
I want extract text left to right

Comment: but the OCRs work exactly left-to-right as I know

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko
Do you know best learning for OCR?
Every training I used was vertical